# Flash AS3 - MouseEvent

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, actionscript, flash-cs5

This really is a noobish question, but I honestly don't know how to solve my problem.

I have a function

```
    public function backToSelect(evt:Event, i:Number):void
    {
        removeChild(back);
        switch(i)   {
            case 1:
                removeChild(speel1);
                break;
            //etc
        }
        gotoAndStop('home');

     }
```

I don't know how to call this function. I tried doing

```
        back.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, backToSelect(1));
```

But then flash complains:

```
1067: Implicit coercion of a value of type int to an unrelated type flash.events:Event.
```

I realise my error here, I skipped the first argument (namely the Event one) when doing `backToSelect(1)`. However, I don't know what to put there to call my function correctly. I tried everything, ranging from `evt:MouseEvent` to just `MouseEvent` and other stuff. Nothing worked. Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can't pass custom parameters in stock event listeners. This is something only custom events can do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So the Event system in Flash is kind of baked in - when you use "addEventListener()" what you're saying is "Hey, when you get an event of type X, pass that event to the function I'm supplying. That function accepts a single argument, which is the event that I'm listening for."

You're not actually making a function call inside of "addEventListener()" - you'd pass in backToSelect, not backToSelect(). The difference is that the first one is a reference to that function - you're not saying "Call this function now!" you're saying "put this aside and use it whenever that event fires."

So where does that leave you? This is an incredibly common problem for people new to the Flash environment, and the solution is not necessarily obvious. What you're going to want to do is find a way to associate your data with the target of the mouse click. The simplest way to do that is simply something like this:

```
public function backToSelect(evt:Event):void
    {
        removeChild(back);
        switch(e.currentTarget)   {
            case buttonOne:
                removeChild(speel1);
                break;
            //etc
        }
        gotoAndStop('home');

     }
```

Without a more comprehensive understanding of what you're trying to do it's difficult for me to advise your more specifically, but this is the root of it. You can either put all of your logic into your click handler or you can do something a bit fancier, like creating a Dictionary object that associates numbers with buttons and then just use num = myDictionary[e.currentTarget] or whatever.

But yeah, that's what's going on at the core there. I hope that helps, let me know if you'd like more specific help!

Comment: Thanks; I tried this but then I ran into a new problem. Switching over the current target doesn't get me anywhere, because the 'back' button is always the same. It's like this: I have four levels in a game, each with a different instruction screen. They use the same back button to go to the homepage. However, I have four different play buttons.. Perhaps faulty design. Anyway, I want to remove the play button of instruction screen x when I press 'back'. To know on which instr screen we are, I wanted to pass this to the backToSelect() function by using an argument. If that makes sense?

Comment: Sure. So basically somewhere you need to be keeping a reference to which screen you want to remove. Create a var called currentScreen:InstructionScreenClass and every time you go to a different level just say currentScreen = whatever it should be. Then in your back handler all you have to do is say "removeChild(currentScreen)" - make sense?

Answer (score 1):

If you wish to invoke the specific function, this is the way to do it:

```
  back.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, 
       function (evt:MouseEvent):void { backToSelect(evt, 1); } );
```

This wrapper function statement is an anonymous function with the exact signature ActionScript expects for a MouseEvent.CLICK handler. However, the proper way is the one below:

```
  // somewhere else in your class, presumably...
  function mouseEventHandler(evt:MouseEvent):void {
      backToSelect(evt, 1);
  }

  back.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, mouseEventHandler);
```

This will enable you to remove the handler should you need to, later on.

Comment: That will work, but it is NOT a best practice. Putting a function literal into your addEventListener() call is a VERY bad habit to get into, because it makes it exponentially more difficult to keep track of what's happening where. This is known as an anonymous function closure, and while it's a useful technique in certain cases it's dangerous to use if you don't understand all of the implications.

Comment: The first solution presented here does exactly what I want, but I don't really want to use it since it's not considered good practice. The second function doesn't get me anywhere as far as I can tell; because I'd have to create multiple functions to get to the 4 different levels? Or am I wrong?

Comment: I agree, it is a bit complicated. If you can rewrite your functions to conform to event handler signatures, you're ok. Just keep in mind that's it might save you some time and effort to avoid code duplication, so if you want to invoke a piece of code in two distinct places, I suggest you place it in a function and invoke that in a separate event handler, just for those times when you need it.